# Fullcalendar v5.7.0, no dividing lines between days in week mode

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have Fullcalendar v5.7.0 but there's no dividing lines between days in the week mode. Also current day in the week isn't highlighted.
[image]

The initialization code

```
 function showCalendar() {
        if ($('#calendar__teacher-events').length) {
            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar__teacher-events');
            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'prev,today,next',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                initialDate: new Date(),
                locale: 'en',
                editable: false,
                contentHeight: 'auto',
                navLinks: true,
                dayMaxEventRows: 5,
                eventTimeFormat: {
                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    meridiem: false
                },
                eventMaxStack: 3
            });
            calendar.render();
        }
    }
```

I was trying examples from other topics, but nothing worked for me.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not reproducible - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyWyMQG . You probably have some other CSS in your page which is accidentally interfering with fullCalendar.

Comment: Yes, this is really it, there were other CSS that made all this. Thank you for re clue and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really were other css that does all that staff. I checked it and solved.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this styling solved my problem, I experienced the same problem when using fullCalendar on my svelte project

```
.fc .fc-scrollgrid-section .fc-timegrid-cols table {
    height: 100%;
}
```